# Change iframe src for specific div class

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe

There is this plugin (envato elements) I did install, there is Welcome section in the backed where plugin displays iframe video tutorial - I would like to change the iframe video src and replace this video with my own. Is it possible and how this can be done? This site is for client, I would like to hide existing video and replace it with my own tutorial.

Current code:

```
<div class="_1XZyE9kXFS3DmtFB0rHJL1"><iframe class="_2QxVLhRMsBFh3j3aZyu82n" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1"></iframe></div>
```

What is the best way to change this video? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“Tried css, but not working.”_ - CSS can not change any video element _source_ for you, pointless attempt to begin with. _“What is the best way to change this video?”_ - depends on the context, of which you have given us virtually none at all.

Comment: Changing the src of an iframe just sounds wrong.  Why do you need this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery, the solution would be

```
var url = "URL to be added"
$("iframe [class=_2QxVLhRMsBFh3j3aZyu82n]").attr('src',url);
```

To add this in the code,
Find the line in your code where jQuery is imported. It will look like this

Just below that, add a script tag and add the code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = "URL to be added"
$("iframe [class=_2QxVLhRMsBFh3j3aZyu82n]").attr('src',url);

});
```

Comment: thanks. what is the right place to add it?

Comment: edited the answer to show where to add it